# SQL Server 2005: Delete Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

Is this the most efficient way to delete from `DeletedProducts` table where there are not references found in the `ProductFileInfo` table?

Sample:

```
DELETE FROM DeletedProducts 
WHERE ProductId NOT IN SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM ProductFileInfo
```

Or is `NOT EXIST` a better way to perform this.

Note: `ProductFileInfo` has over 20 Million records in it.

SQL Server 2005 Standard is what I am using.

Thanks

Comment: If you post (T-SQL) code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT IN and NOT EXISTS will probably produce the same plan. How many rows are you going to delete? If it is a lot I would do batches of 5K or 10K  this way you won't fill your LOG with one big transaction and then if it fails for whatever reason it needs to do a big rollback

for example

```
DELETE top 5000
from sometable
where ....
go 100 --will be executed 100 times
```

in order for GO N to work you need SSMS and service pack 2 (IIRC)  but of course you can also write a while loop..`while @@rowcount > 0`.......

Answer (score 0):

try multiple solutions and test their performance, YMMV.
Also try an outer join

```
DELETE FROM DeletedProducts d left outer join ProductFileInfo p
on d.ProductId  = p.ProductId  WHERE p.ProductID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I typically write something along the lines of

```
delete d
from TableToDeleteFrom d
where not exists(select top 1 1 from SomeOtherTable sot where sot.ThatId = d.ThatId)
```

Probably, you don't want to lock the look-up table, so you can specify `with(readpast)` hint or `with(nolock)`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a great resource for exactly what your asking.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/t_sql_where_p3.aspx

Comment: I looked at the first couple of tips and they seem extremely dubious (maybe they were once true but they are flat out incorrect for SQL Server 2005+)

Comment: Thats pretty unfair of you, this was written by a well respected author in the community, and I have seen multiple presentations given on multiple pieces of it by other respected presenters as recently as 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @daytona - I was a bit surprised as well that Brad McGehee's name was besides that. I wonder if he wrote it some time ago and some one else updated it to say it applied to SQL2005. In SQL 2005+ though [Not In vs Not Exists](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/) and [In vs Exists](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/). Do some experimentation yourself. If you find any different let me know!

Comment: And also of interest [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)